# CSS Overlay hovering views wrong div

Tags: html, css

This is my first time trying an overlay. It is somewhat working however, hovering the first image would overlay below.. I tried making the position absolute, but that means that overlay would stay at top.

```html
<div class="galleryContainer">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="galleryItem">
         <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Gold-jewellery-jewel-henry-designs-terabass.jpg"/>
         <div class="imgCaption">
            <p>lulz</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
         <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_HEjoNp_qRz8/TSsQZNyVFUI/AAAAAAAAJhI/xc7MCnnNYZY/s1600/World%2527s+Most+Funniest+Animals+Photos+%25288%2529.jpg"/>
         <div class="imgCaption">
            <p>lulz</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="galleryItem">
         <img src="http://funny-pics-fun.com/wp-content/uploads/Very-Funny-And-Creative-Ads-Using-Animals-19.jpg"/>
         <div class="imgCaption">
            <p>lulz</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="galleryItem">
         <img src="http://funny-pics-fun.com/wp-content/uploads/Very-Funny-And-Creative-Ads-Using-Animals-18.jpg"/>
         <div class="imgCaption">
            <p>yaw</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
.row {
    margin:2%;
}
.row .galleryItem {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5%;
    width:300px;
    height:350px;
}

.row .galleryItem img {
    width:280px;
    height:330px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


.row .galleryItem .imgCaption {
    top: 0px;
    width:300px; 
    height:350px; 
    background:#FF2400; 
    opacity:0; 
}

.row .galleryItem .imgCaption p {
    color:white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.row .galleryItem:hover .imgCaption {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.galleryContainer {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0ktzo08/) I made that demonstrates the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u0ktzo08/ Since it won't let me post my jsfiddle above, here is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your caption is positioned wrongly. It can be finished by adding `float:left;` to your img.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0ktzo08/1/).

EDIT:

Other changes:
The caption div didn't fade properly so I switched the show up method from, `opacity:0` -> `opacity: 0.7;`, to `display:none` -> `display: block`.

I removed the margins and paddings from the `<p>` element since it appeared displaced.